# Windows 7 paint annoyances

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-paint

When i draw lines with windows 7 paint it gives me little squares at the edges that i can move the lines with. This is annoying because when drawing lots of lines that are connected to each other i have to select another tool and then the line again to draw a line that start on one of the ends of the existing line.

Is there any way to turn this off?

Comment: You might think there must be an easy solution for this, like pressing enter, space or anything, or by double-clicking. But no, it's Microsoft after all!

Comment: Apparently you can't beat perfection, need to upgrade to the older version.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Drawing lots of lines that are connected is usually something that calls for the polyline tool instead of multiple individual lines:

[image: Polygon tool in Windows 7's Paint]

Otherwise you can install Paint.NET where you get those handles too, but you can commit the drawn line with the <kbd>Return</kbd> key.

Answer (score 2):

> When i draw lines with windows 7 paint
>   it gives me little squares at the
>   edges that i can move the lines with.

I know exactly what you mean and i don't know how to turn off this annoyance.

If you're looking for a fast, leight-weight alternative, that is running circles around MS Paint, have a look at **[PhotoFiltre](http://photofiltre.free.fr/frames_en.htm)** (feature-packed and certainly no "little squares at the edges" :)

[image]

*PhotoFiltre is freeware, a portable version is available (doesn't require installation).*

Answer (score 2):

I can't find a way of getting it to do such either, very annoying.

I know there are other paint apps that do it, but they're quite heavyweight.  I use full featured ones sometimes, but other times I like the speed and simplicity of mspaint.

So I wrote the following workaround.

You'll have to download and install autohotkey first.  Then create a blank file called mspaint.ahk (ensure you have view file extensions on) and paste the following:

```
~Space::
    if WinActive("ahk_class MSPaintApp")
    {
        MouseMove 20, 20, 0, R
        MouseClick
        MouseMove 0, -20, 0, R
        MouseClick
        MouseMove -20, 0, 0, R
    }
Return
```

Run the file.  Now at the end of each line press space and it'll automatically click off and return to the exact location it was before, almost as fast as the time it takes to let go of the space bar so it doesn't slow your drawing.

(Don't worry it doesn't activate in any other program other than mspaint because that could get annoying!

Answer (score 1):

So annoying, especially since MS hasnt finished the line tool instructions on this in the help file.
But I found if you move mouse pointer further away from the line, the cursor changes from a move indicator to a cross hair, and if you click anywhere while it is a cross hair, then it finishes the line. WHile the line still has selector squares on the ends, you can still move either end point, or even move the whole line. Have a play.
MS has just dropped the ball in the help, and consequently creating more angry people. Millions of them no doubt.